# Which file structure for pages should relate to `login//?username=` path in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I have redirect url which redirects user to `login//?username=` in my nextjs app. I tried

- `pages/login/index.tsx`
- `pages/login/[username].tsx`
- `pages/login/[rest].tsx`
- `pages/login/[...rest].tsx`

but all resulted in 404 for that url

I already have `pages/[...dep].tsx` which working fine for ulrs like `one/two/three`, maybe there is some conflict with this url? Isn't `login//?username` should be handled by same page handler if I don't have `pages/login/` present?

Comment: My solution for now was to add handler inside 404 page in case that param is present - `username` (the one redirect attaches to url)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that you have double slashes in your login url.

If you remove the second slash (`login/?username=`) it will map to `pages/login/index.tsx`.

Comment: Yes, I have suspicion this is the problem but for now we were unable to find where in Cognito this is configured. So let's pretend I can't change that - how to fix this on nextjs side? Or is it a bug in nextjs routing system?

Comment: It is a bug in the usage, Next.js maps url to file, there is not such thing folder with an empty name, which what your url represents.

Comment: But `[...rest]` should allow capturing any leftovers, isn't it? `{"": "tst"}` is possible in js, so it should map it or not?

Comment: I guess i try to report it as bug in their repo, and wait for answer from devs then

Comment: yeah, there is already a bug for this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/13011